How to delete a single object in an array where a SwiftData Model has an Array of another Model
I have an SwiftData Model called Exercise that stores an array of the Sets model
@Model
class Exercise: Identifiable {
    var id: UUID
    var exerciseName: ExerciseName
    
    @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade)
    var sets: [Set]?    //When an Exercise gets Deleted all Sets associated need to get deleted
    var date: Date
    var workout: Workout?       //it can belong to a work but it doesnt have to

@Model
class Set: Identifiable {
    var id: UUID
    var weight: Int
    var reps: Int
    var isCompleted: Bool
    var exercise: Exercise

Now in my code I have a Boolean called onComplete that when set to false should 1. delete the set from the Sets model and Delete it from Exercise.sets:
func save() {
    //first inserting the sets into the Sets model
    for set in sets {
        if(set.isCompleted){
            //    let newSet = set
            modelContext.insert(set)
            exercise.sets?.append(set)
            print("\(exercise.sets!)")
            print("\(sets)")
            //  exercise.sets?.append(set)
        } else {
           //Else the toggle was set to false so we both dont append it and we delete it
            print("this set was not toggled")
            //how do i delete it from exerice.sets here??
            modelContext.delete(set)
        }
        
    }

right now this code causes the following error:

CoreData: annotation: repairing missing delete propagation for to-many relationship sets on object


Does it help if you add the inverse: argument to your @Relationship declaration?

research cascade

As Joakim suggested adding inverse in the relationship resolved the issue:
@Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade,inverse: \Set.exercise) var sets: [Set]?

Adding this meant when a set is deleted it will not only be Deleted from the Set model but also directly from the sets array in Exercise since it has a non optional Exercise it belongs to, SwiftData will do this for you there is not need to delete it from exercise.sets manually(that will actually throw an error).
